# How can I create a list pulling data from another list of objects

Tags: java, list, javafx

Let's say I have a list of objects of this type:

```
ObjectA {
    public String a;
    public String b;
}
```

Is there any way I can create a new list containing all the `ObjectA.a` from the first list, where if I change the value in the first list, it will also change the values in the second list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ObservableList<ObjectA> objectList = ...;
ObservableList<String> stringAList = EasyBind.map(objectList, obj -> obj.a);
```

This solution uses the [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) library.

Answer (score 0):

No. Since the String class is immutable, you cannot do something like `objectA.getA().set("new string")`.

The only way to change the value of instance "a" is to say a =" new string value...". Thus this creates a new String object and makes the reference "a" refer to it. Therefore the changes are not reflected in the second list.

Answer (score -1):

You have list. 
list1
now create new list for example list2
and now simply assigns list2 into list1
list2 = list1
list2 is only refference to list1. Data in these two lists are in memory only once.
If you change elements in list1, it also changes in list2.

Comment: I don't want list2 to just be a copy of list1; I want list2 to be a list of type String, which contains Object.a, not just the Object itself.